# Transferring a value from fortran to C++ so that it appears as a numeric_limits<float> in c++ via shared memory

Tags: c++, fortran

I need to transfer a number from fortran to C++, so that when it's read in c++ it is treated as a numeric_limits::quiet_nan(). We're using Salford/Intel compilers on the Fortran side and VS2010 on the C++, using the shared memory in Windows.

Any ideas,
James

Comment: Accidentally pressed return before finishing it.

Comment: It happens to the best. The question still needs lots of work, though. Please do provide a bit of code and context.

Answer (score 3):

The Fortran 2003 standard defines an intrinsic module `ieee_arithmetic` which contains, *inter alia*, the definitions of a derived type called `ieee_class_type`.  The same module also defines a bunch of named constants of that type, the name of one of those named constants is `ieee_quiet_nan`.

`ieee_arithmetic` also defines a function `ieee_value` which takes 2 arguments; the first of these (call it `x`) is a real, and the second (called `class`) takes a value of type `ieee_class_type` such as `ieee_quiet_nan` so the function call `ieee_value(x,ieee_quiet_nan)` will return an IEEE quiet NaN of the same type and kind as `x`.

Note that this function only works if the function call `ieee_support_nan(x)` returns `.true.`. Fortran processors are not required to support all features of IEEE arithmetic and for portability it's always best to check first for the feature(s) you want to use.

I guess, therefore, that if your Fortran and C++ programs are sharing memory, a Fortran statement such as

`y = ieee_value(x,ieee_quiet_nan)`

will put bits into the location specified by the name `y` which your C++ program will understand to be a quiet NaN.

**EDIT**

If, as Vladimir F tells us, Salford's Fortran lacks `ieee_arithmetic` I suppose you'll have to fall back on Fortran's bit-twiddling facilities.  Declare an integer variable with the number of bits you want in C++, find out what the valid bit patterns are for a quiet NaN, then it should be plane sailing.

Comment: I doubt Salford support this. They are not heading towards Fortran 2003 AFAIK.